# Running a script before angular dev server reloads the app

Tags: angular, webpack-dev-server

I am working on an Angular project and want to perform some action before my changes gets reloaded on the browser by dev server which watches the files for changes. I tried finding a hook that will let me do my job but unable to find any such hook.

Currently, I am running that script before ng serve. But I would like to run that script every time I am making changes to scss files of the application.

Thanks in Advance.